# Adding CSS files to Savant

Tags: html, css, styles

I'm trying to set up my website with Savant Web Server (http://savant.sourceforge.net/). This works very well with .html and image files, but if I add my CSS file to style the website, Savant just ignores it and leaves the website with no styling. Does Savant even support CSS and how can I make the file work on it?

Comment: You should try to check the documentation or try to include a <style> tag into your head and see if CSSs works in that way.

Comment: Check if the CSS file is pushed in the correct mime type (text/css) from the server. Use the developer tools (F12 Key) provided by your Browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Incorrect_MIME_Type_for_CSS_Files